# Display which check boxes have been checked

Tags: php

I have an array of numbers and would like to create a check box for each element in the array. Once the submit button is pressed the check boxes which were selected will be displayed. Is there a way to do this?

PHP code :

```
<?php

    $arr = array("1","2","3","4");

    //Create a checkbox for each array element
    foreach($arr as $index=>$value)
    {
    echo ' <input type="checkbox" name = "checkb[]"value="'.$value.'">'; 

    }

    echo'<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "submit">';

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    foreach($_POST['checkb'] as $checkb)
    {
    echo $checkb." ";
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do it. Where is your form (I only see `input` but no `form`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont have any `form` to `post` `checkbox` value, use `form` tag and, you can use `in_array()` for checked checkbox:

```
<?php

    $arr = array("1","2","3","4");

    //Create a checkbox for each array element
    foreach($arr as $index=>$value)
    {
    echo '<form action="" method="post">';
    echo ' <input type="checkbox" name = "checkb[]"value="'.$value.'">'; 

    }

    echo'<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "submit"></form>';

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    foreach($_POST['checkb'] as $checkb)
    {
     if(in_array($checkb,$arr))
    {
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name = "checkb[]"value="'.$checkb.'" checked>';
    }
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: The check boxes which are checked are still not being displayed.

Comment: I still cant get it to display which check boxes have been selected